# Bootstrap 3 - Disapear the dropdown menu when i click in a link

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got a dropdown menu, but it does not work well,

This is the HTML code:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle"><img src="img/ico_menu_off.png" /></a>
        <div id="MainMenu" class="dropdown-menu">
          <div class="list-group panel">
            <a href="#demo3" class="dropdown-toggle list-group-item list-group-item-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">Links to Portals</a>
            <div class="collapse" id="demo3">
              <a href="#SubMenu1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#SubMenu1">Portal 1 <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
              <a href="#SubMenu1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#SubMenu1">Portal 2 <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
              <a href="#SubMenu1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#SubMenu1">Portal 3 <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
              <a href="#SubMenu1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#SubMenu1">Portal 4 <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
            </div>
            <a href="#demo4" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">Links to Calculators</a>
            <div class="collapse" id="demo4">
              <a href="" class="list-group-item">Portal 1</a>
              <a href="" class="list-group-item">Portal 2</a>
              <a href="" class="list-group-item">Portal 3</a>
            </div>
             <a href="#demo5" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">Links to Tools</a>
            <div class="collapse" id="demo5">
              <a href="" class="list-group-item">Portal 1</a>
              <a href="" class="list-group-item">Portal 2</a>
              <a href="" class="list-group-item">Portal 3</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </li>   
</ul>
```

This is the CSS code:

```
#customer-information .list-group.panel > .list-group-item {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px
}
#customer-information .list-group-submenu {
  margin-left:20px;
}
```

I need when I click in one option, the menu don`t disapear, The menu should be closed only when performed click on the icon displays the menu

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a click listner to prevent menu closing:

```
$("[data-parent='#MainMenu']").on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    var dest = $(this).attr('href');
    $(dest).collapse('toggle');
});
```

In this way, the dropdown will not close when you click first level options. You use `stopPropagation` even for second level items if you want to prevent closing also in this case.

Note that you can change the selector according your needs. For example, `$("#MainMenu>div>a")` will give you the same results in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I have more or less the same problem, but I could not close the drop-down submenus and function that is set in the previous comment, it don't work me properly.

HTML is the same as the one already laid here and have the following functions:

```
//Ocultar menu cuando se haga click fuera del mismo
    $(document).on('click', function (e) {
    //$(document).on("click", "body", function(e) {
        //Target => collapse('hide')
       if($("#MainMenu").hasClass('in')) {
           $("#MainMenu").collapse("hide");
       }
       //stop the code from bubbling up
       e.stopPropagation();
       e.preventDefault();      
    });

    $(document).on("click", function() {
        $("#MainMenu>div>a").on('click', function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        var dest = $(this).attr('href');
        $(dest).collapse('toggle');
     });
    });
```

how I can do that when I drop-down a submenu hide a submenu which is open?

Thanks